# Search text within Varchar(max) column of Sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, varcharmax

I wanted to write a t-sql query which finds values within a column of a sql server table.

Example,

```
CREATE TABLE Transactions (Details varchar(max));
```

Details Column has below type strings stored in it

```
ID=124|NAME=JohnDoe|DATE=020620121025|ISPRIMARY=True|
TRANSACTION_AMOUNT=124.36|DISCOUNT_AMOUNT=10.00|STATE=GA|
ADDR1=test|ADDR2=test22|OTHER=OtherDetailsHere

ID=6257|NAME=michael|DATE=050320111255|ISPRIMARY=False|
TRANSACTION_AMOUNT=4235.00|DISCOUNT_AMOUNT=33.25|STATE=VA|
ADDR1=test11|ADDR2=test5|OTHER=SomeOtherDetailsHere
```

Objective is to write query which gives below output

```
 Name     |   Transaction Amount | Discount
 -------------------------------------------
 JohnDoe  |   124.36             | 10.00
 michael  |   4235.00            | 33.25
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you storing your data pipe delimited in a single column -- these fields should be added as columns to the table.

However, if that isn't an option, you'll need to use string manipulation.  Here's one option using a couple Common Table Expressions, along with `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX`:

```
WITH CTE1 AS (
  SELECT 
      SUBSTRING(Details, 
            CHARINDEX('|NAME=', DETAILS) + LEN('|NAME='), 
            LEN(Details)) NAME,
      SUBSTRING(Details, 
            CHARINDEX('|TRANSACTION_AMOUNT=', DETAILS) + LEN('|TRANSACTION_AMOUNT='), 
            LEN(Details)) TRANSACTION_AMOUNT,
      SUBSTRING(Details, 
            CHARINDEX('|DISCOUNT_AMOUNT=', DETAILS) + LEN('|DISCOUNT_AMOUNT='), 
            LEN(Details)) DISCOUNT_AMOUNT
  FROM Transactions
), CTE2 AS (
  SELECT 
      SUBSTRING(NAME,1,CHARINDEX('|',NAME)-1) NAME,
      SUBSTRING(TRANSACTION_AMOUNT,1,CHARINDEX('|',TRANSACTION_AMOUNT)-1) TRANSACTION_AMOUNT,
      SUBSTRING(DISCOUNT_AMOUNT,1,CHARINDEX('|',DISCOUNT_AMOUNT)-1) DISCOUNT_AMOUNT
  FROM CTE1
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE2
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/65d71/1)

Comment: Hi @sgeddes,  Your answer solves the problem mentioned in test scenario, however when implementing same solution with real data, it doesnot work, unable to identify what could be the reason, Could you please see feedle with real data here at [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dea4e/1)     Thanks

Comment: Nope, It was my mistake...Your solution works...You made my day! Thanks you so much :-)